# Git Mergetool - auto accept non conflicted merges

Tags: git

When I use git mergetool it requires me confirm all merged files rather than simply accepting non conflicting merges and only prompting me to resolve conflicts, which is my preferred behavior.

Are there options/.switches to enable this?

--- EDIT ---

Perhaps this is nothing to do with git and is related to my choice of mergetool :  KDiff?

Comment: mergetool should only be asking you to resolve conflicts that actually exist; are you sure you're really getting the behavior you describe?

Comment: For me it only prompts for conflicting files. I have not configured anything w.r.t. mergetool in my .gitconfig.

Comment: Yes, I'm certain that it prompts for non-conflicted files.  I'm using git4windows to initiate the merge, but it drops out to console (I use gitbash, not that it should matter) at which point I simply run git mergetool.  I have configure git to use Kdiff, perhaps this is the culprit and not git at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have broken the config somehow haivng install Git4Windows and GitExtensions and just generally hacking away at it.  A clean install of G4W sorting it all out.